# How to create a custom UIView with a subview inside, setting its size/position with AutoLayout programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I would like to create a custom `UIView`, say `TestLabelView`, which contains a label whose margin would be 16px.

It would look like this:

[image]

Here is how I tried to create this custom `UIView` and instantiated it in a view controller:

**TestLabelView**

```
class TestLabelView: UIView {
    private var label = UILabel()
    
    var text: String = "" { didSet { updateUI() } }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        internalInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        internalInit()
    }
    
    private func internalInit() {
        backgroundColor = .red
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(label)
    }
    
    private func updateUI() {
        label.text = text
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label,
                           attribute: .leading,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: self,
                           attribute: .leading,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: 24).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                           attribute: .trailing,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: label,
                           attribute: .trailing,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: 24).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: label,
                           attribute: .top,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: self,
                           attribute: .top,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: 24).isActive = true
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: self,
                           attribute: .bottom,
                           relatedBy: .equal,
                           toItem: label,
                           attribute: .bottom,
                           multiplier: 1,
                           constant: 24).isActive = true
        setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var testLabelView: TestLabelView?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        testLabelView?.text = "This is a test view with a test label, contained in multiple lines"
    }
}
```

**In the storyboard**

[image]

*I have set a placeholder intrinsic size to remove the storyboard error, and the bottom margin is greater than or equal to 24px, so the view height should be set depending on the content size*

However by doing so, I don't see the label appearing. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Thank you for your help

Comment: You don't have a `Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.` in console? If yes, what does it say? Also, what's the final frame of the label? What does says the View debug Hierarchy of Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html

Comment: Perhaps you are missing `label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank Thank you, that was the reason!

Comment: @Larme Thank you for your answer, sure I should learn how to better use the view debug hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code for your `TestLabelView` view

```swift
class TestLabelView: UIView {
    private var label : UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.numberOfLines = 0
        return l
    }()
    
    var text: String = "" { didSet { self.label.text = self.text } }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        internalInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        internalInit()
    }
    
    private func internalInit() {
        backgroundColor = .red
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(label)
        setConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            self.label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            self.label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            self.label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
        ])
    }
}
```